# MAPI not Defined

Tags: python, outlook

I had a code that ran well for 3 months up until now I have started seeing errors and not sure what needs revision

My original code was this:

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
root_folder = namespace.Folders.Item(3)
subfolder = root_folder.Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Daily Process']
messages = subfolder.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
subj_line = message.subject
```

However I am getting the following error

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found.', None, 0, -2147221233), None)
```

I broke my code down and seems like the name 'MAPI' is not longer defined

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
your_folder = namespace.Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Daily Process']
for message in your_folder.Items:
    print(message.Subject)
```

Which gives me

```
name 'mapi' is not defined
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if this snippet ever worked. Do you mean `mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")`?

Comment: HI Jacques, I used namespace = ~ . Please see revised code

Comment: @AliShaikh Jacques is suggesting how to fix the error. The problem is that you have nothing named `mapi`. One way to fix it is to initialize the variable to the correct value with `mapi = ...`. Alternatively, you can do `namespace.Folders...`. I suggest that you learn how variables work in python.

Comment: Tried that too, stil the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try in lower case:

```py
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("outlook.application")
```

I also had the same error when I put capitalized Outlook